# How to load video (image sequences) to become data input for CNN-LSTM deep learning model?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, lstm

In my project, I have two class for the data, "abnormal" and "normal". I have separated training and validation folder for this two type of data. The structure as follow:
Each video file includes the image frames of the video clip, different video folder contain different number of frame. Now, I need to load the frames into the model as the data input and label them into one group. How can i do that? I use keras API.

```
train
------abnormal
--------------video1
---------------------image1
---------------------image3
---------------------image3
---------------------image...
--------------video2
--------------video3
--------------video...

------normal
(the same as above)
```

Comment: repeat the same label for all frames in the folder?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can have all the images into a single folder and rename them such as 1.normal.jpg, 1.abnormal.jpg. This way you will reduce the time taken to open the folder of a particular class and read images.

Once you rename them, you can split into labels using the given method:

```
def label(img): 
    word_label = img.split('.')[-2]
    if word_label == 'normal':
        return 1 
    elif word_label == 'abnormal':
        return 0
```